ERROR: relation "arbitrarySchemaName.databasechangelog" does not exist
I am working on an existing service which uses liquibase and has its table all set up in its deployed environments. I am attempting to build the db in my local for testing but I can't get past this error -
Caused by: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: ERROR: relation "arbitrarySchemaName.databasechangelog" does not exist
  Position: 8 [Failed SQL: (0) UPDATE arbitrarySchemaName.databasechangelog SET MD5SUM = NULL]

It seems to be having trouble creating the databasechangelog which is managed by liquibase. I am confused by what it means that the relation does not exist. I wouldn't think there should be any relationship between the changelog and other tables.
I have set up other db tables in my service that use liquibase and this was never an issue.  I just repeated the commands to do so for another service so I am confident that is not the issue but nevertheless they are
psql postgres
CREATE schema <schema>;
create user <user>;
grant all privileges on database postgres to <user>;
grant all privileges on schema <schema> to <user>;

and then in my yaml I include these properties
    jdbcUrl: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres?currentSchema=arbitrarySchemaName&stringtype=unspecified
    username: postgres


spring:
  liquibase:
    default-schema: arbitrarySchemaName
    enabled: true

I attempted to create the table myself but then it says that it does not have permission to access the table (even after I re-granted the permissions via grant all privileges on schema <schema> to <user>; ).

Do you have a database schema called schema ? Check the result from this query: SELECT nspname FROM pg_namespace WHERE nspname = 'schema';

Yes, I do. Well technically its called cssv2 but I changed it to try to make it more clear.  `nspname
cssv2
(1 row)`

Not clear, is the name for this schema schema or cssv2? What is it? And if it's cssv2, you should use this name because that's where your table is located.

If you could "create the table yourself" then it wasn't there, yet. If you create it yourself, make sure the role accessing it has been granted  the necessary privileges.

Please do not change the schema and table names in your question. Perhaps the problem is with the names. The statement in your question would cause a syntax error, so I'll have to vote to close as "unable to reproduce".
